# Getting Firestore document ID when mapping Collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a List View in Flutter using

```
          ...snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

but I'd like to delete a document from firebase when it's corresponding List Tile is pressed

I was thinking of using

```
              onTap: () async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('User Data')
                    .doc('document_id')
                    .delete();
              },
```

to do so but I need the document_id how do **I get the document ID when mapping** ?

here is my full code

```
          ...snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('User Data')
                    .doc('document_id')
                    .delete();
              },
              child: HomeCard(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DocumentSnapshot` class has an `id` property.

```dart
         ...snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('User Data')
                    .doc(document.id)
                    .delete();
              },
              child: HomeCard(
```

You can check the docs on the [Flutter api page.](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)